# Pyspark merge columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Have data frame as below

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  a|  c|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
|  z| z1|  a|  z|
|  b| z2|  a|  c|
|  c| z3|  b|  a|
|  d| z4|  a|  a|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I need to combine common column expected output like this

```
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
+---+---+
|  z | a |
|  z | z |
|  b | a |
|  b | c |
|  c | b |
|  c | a |
|  d | a |
|  d | a |
|  z1| a |
|  z1| z |
|  z2| a |
|  z2| c |
|  z3| b |
|  z3| a |
|  z4| a |
|  z4| a |
+---+---+
```

I tried this code

```
old_col=df.schema.names
running_list=[]
new_col=[]
i=0
for column in old_col:
    if(column in running_list):
    new_col.append(column+"_"+str(i))
    i=i+1
    else:
    new_col.append(column)
    running_list.append(column)
print(new_col)

df1 = df.toDF(*new_col)
```

It's dropped only duplicates not combine data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with the following

```
from pyspark.sql import types, functions

schema = (types.StructType([
        types.StructField('a', types.StringType()),
        types.StructField('c', types.StringType()),
        ]))

df = df.toDF(*["a","b","c","d"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), schema)

for c1 in ["a", "b"]:
    for c2 in ["c", "d"]:
        df2=df2.union(df.select(c1,c2).withColumnRenamed(c1,"a").withColumnRenamed(c2,"c"))
```

To get the following result

```
df2.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  c|
+---+---+
|  z|  a|
|  b|  a|
|  c|  b|
|  d|  a|
|  z|  z|
|  b|  c|
|  c|  a|
|  d|  a|
| z1|  a|
| z2|  a|
| z3|  b|
| z4|  a|
| z1|  z|
| z2|  c|
| z3|  a|
| z4|  a|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Note that I used different column names as `a` and `c` to make the columns unique

Comment: Thanks but I have duplicate column names this solution not worked

Comment: Edited my answer to use your column names